# How CV determines which function to use?

Tags: catboost

I am confused with CV class. I thought it accepts a regressor or classifier model like in scikit-learn. However, I haven't found any such model in the input of CV. Could you please tell how CV class determines which model to fit?

Answer (score 1):

CatBoost doesn't have a CV class. But there is a cv function in CatBoost Python library.
The function accepts parameter `params` which should contail all the parameters that describe the model you want to cross-validate.